# "Rotate" data around center in excel

Tags: excel

Can anyone help me "rotate" my 24 x 16 table?

I essentially want the top right position A1 to become Q24 by rotating all data by 180 degrees using the center as a pivot (see attached). I'm not very good with excel.

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: Do you just need to rotate values, or are there any formulas/formatting to move?

Comment: In that case the code I posted should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in VBA.  Copy and paste the code below into a regular VBA code module. If you select the area you want to flip and run the "Tester" macro it will rotate the values.

Usage:

```
Sub Tester()
    'FlipRange ActiveSheet.Range("A1:J10") 'work on pre-defined range
    FlipRange Selection 'work on selected range
End Sub
```

Sub:

```
Sub FlipRange(rng As Range)
Dim a, b(), r As Long, c As Long
Dim nR As Long, nC As Long

    a = rng.Value
    nR = UBound(a, 1)
    nC = UBound(a, 2)
    ReDim b(1 To nR, 1 To nC)

    For r = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        For c = 1 To nC
            b((nR - r) + 1, (nC - c) + 1) = a(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    rng.Value = b
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a very well thought out answer and I can see that it works, but can you use VBA on mac excel btw?

Comment: There was a time when there was no VBA on Mac (Excel 2008), but it is now back in Excel 2011.